# Windows 10 ISO won't install from a flash drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows-installation

My laptop is a Lenovo ThinkPad T440. I downloaded the ISO for Windows 10 from Microsoft's website and wrote it on to a flash drive using `dd`. (I'm currently running Fedora 23, so I can't use the media creation tool.) On boot I get this error:

```
Windows Boot Manager

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the
cause. To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer.
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click “Next.”
  3. Click “Repair your computer.”

If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or contact your 
manufacturer for assistance.

    File: \Boot\BCD

    Status: 0xc0000225

    Info: The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains  
          errors.
```

I've also tried to use a different flash drive and a different live OS. I have a feeling It might have something to do with the fact that I only have USB 3.0 ports on my machine. @Ramhound said this shouldn't matter but it's the only thing I can think of. If this is the case will buying a USB 3 flash drive solve the issue or will I just be able to do something in the BIOS to the USB controller?

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely inserting your portable USB drive into a USB 3.0 port (blue). Try to move it to standard USB 2.0. To use USB 3.0, you will need an additional driver from your manufacturer.

Comment: `Lenovo ThinkPad T440` has no USB 2.0 ports. Besides Windows 10 supports booting from USB 3.0 devices out of the box which means it already as the required drivers.

Comment: @Ramhound is correct.

Comment: @Random Guy: thank you!! I have a W540, and I was getting `0xc0000225` missing boot configuration. Moving the USB stick to a non 3.0 port fixed it! I initially discarded your answer as invalid considering the comments, but decided to try it out nonetheless and it worked!